# can not run the command from shell script but it's fine when typing directly into terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am trying to run a shell script with the bellow content

```
ns script.tcl
sleep 100
```

the command `ns` works fine when typing in terminal but says:

```
ns : not found
```

when runing from the shell script.

Comment: I'm guessing `ns` is an alias, or if it's from the `ns2` package, it is not in your `$PATH`. Please [edit] your question and include i) the output of `type ns`; ii) the output of `echo $PATH`; iii) your entire script. Is there a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ns script.tcl
sleep 100
```

What happens if you try running the script with a proper interpreter declaration at the top?  This could possibly load your $PATH, which is how your terminal knows where to find `ns`.

If that doesn't work, you could try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ns script.tcl
sleep 100
```

You should probably point to the path/directory in which your script.tcl is in.  If it's in the same directory as the bash script, then you'd be fine.  But what would happen if your CWD had script.tcl?  It's best to be specific when scripting.  I was able to tell where `ns` was located by running `which ns` in my terminal.

Comment: it says : ns: command not found

Comment: yes the script.tcl is in the same directory as the .sh file is. and i've been using the exact same system when i had fedora 10 and it was ok.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're $PATH is not being set correctly.  Did you try the second example I posted?

Comment: the path is set correctly because when i run ns in terminal it works perfectly. the path is "/home/myusername/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/ns".
when i tried your recommendation to specify the path like this "#!/bin/bash
/home/nima/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/ns script.tcl
sleep 100" the command is working but since there is another ns command inside the script.tcl file the problem still remains.

Comment: Add that directory to your $PATH variable within bash.  Be sure that it comes BEFORE the other paths (prepend to existing $PATH).  Then, your user will prefer that binary to the system binary.